# Can I setup git lfs to publish files to a local directory but point to them via a specific url?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I work on a cluster computing system that makes specific directories available via a web interface, ex: https://data.myuni.edu/external/myproject accessed on the cluster via /storage/mygroup/external/myproject .

I have a git repo that I successfully setup to use lfs, however I'd like to migrate the lfs file storage to point to files that I mirror at the above URL to avoid GitHub lfs storage fees.

Is this possible? If so, how would this be done?